# Google App Script does not work on first form submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Thank you for any help in advance. I have a script that creates and two folders and copies two different folders into the newly created folder. It then moves the folders into a specific folder that holds all the newly created folders. My script works on manual run and all submissions just not the first form submission. Here is my script:

```
function onFormSubmit() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//Returns the currently active spreadsheet, or null if there is none.
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();//Gets the active sheet in a spreadsheet.
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();//Returns the position of the last row that has content.
  var projectNameRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2);//Returns the range with the top left cell at the given coordinates.
  var projectName = projectNameRange.getValues();//Returns the value of the top-left cell in the range. 
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var startcell = sh.getRange('D2').getValue();
  if(! startcell){sh.getRange('D2').setValue(300001);return};
  var colValues = sh.getRange('D2:D').getValues();// get all the values in column D in an array
  var max=0;// define the max variable to a minimal value
    for(var r in colValues){ // iterate the array
      var vv=colValues[r][0].toString().replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');// remove the letters from the string to convert to number
    if(Number(vv)>max){max=vv};// get the highest numeric value in th column, no matter what happens in the column... this runs at array level so it is very fast
   }
   max++ ; // increment to be 1 above max value
sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(), 4).setValue(Utilities.formatString('%06d',max));// and write it back to sheet's last row.
  var projectIdRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 4);
  var projectId = projectIdRange.getValues();//Returns the value of the top-left cell in the range. 
  var clientNameRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 3);
  var clientName = clientNameRange.getValues();
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyy")
  var targetProduction = DriveApp.createFolder(projectId + "_" + "Prod" + "_" + clientName + "_" + projectName + "_" + curDate);
  var targetCreative = DriveApp.createFolder(projectId + "_" + "Cre" + "_" + clientName + "_" + projectName + "_" + curDate);
  var sourceProductionFolder = "TestTempFolder";
  var sourceCreativeFolder = "TestTempFolder2";
  var sourceProduction = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceProductionFolder);
  var sourceCreative = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceCreativeFolder);


 if (sourceProduction.hasNext()) {
    copyFolderProduction(sourceProduction.next(), targetProduction);

  }

  if (sourceCreative.hasNext()) {
    copyFolderCreative(sourceCreative.next(), targetCreative);
  }

    DriveApp.getFolderById('0BwrizIzPM38bUGFPV2E1Q0JSMms').addFolder(targetProduction);
 DriveApp.removeFolder(targetProduction);
   DriveApp.getFolderById('0BwrizIzPM38bUGFPV2E1Q0JSMms').addFolder(targetCreative);
  DriveApp.removeFolder(targetCreative);


  function copyFolderProduction(sourceProduction, targetProduction) {

  var folders = sourceProduction.getFolders();
  var files  = sourceProduction.getFiles();

  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.makeCopy(file.getName(), targetProduction);
  }

  while(folders.hasNext()) {
    var subFolder = folders.next();
    var folderName = subFolder.getName();
    var targetFolder = targetProduction.createFolder(folderName);
    copyFolderCreative(subFolder, targetFolder);
  }
  }
  function copyFolderCreative(sourceCreative, targetCreative) {

   var folders = sourceCreative.getFolders();
   var files   = sourceCreative.getFiles();

  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.makeCopy(file.getName(), targetCreative);
  }

  while(folders.hasNext()) {
    var subFolder = folders.next();
    var folderName = subFolder.getName();
    var targetFolder = targetCreative.createFolder(folderName);
    copyFolderCreative(subFolder, targetFolder);
   }
  }
 }
```

I am not sure if I am missing something or doing something wrong. But it does work if I manually run the script or on any submission other then the first one. I greatly appreciated any help.

Comment: The script will also insert the projectId into the projectId column but it will not create the folders or move and folders and files.

Answer (score 0):

If this is run from a newly created spreadsheet, it first needs to be opened by a human and granted permissions to run.
I have encountered this issue myself and have solved it by creating a small 'initialise permissions' script. That can be run when the spreadsheet is first created in order to grant all necessary permissions, and which in effect does nothing. But the code forces Google Apps to seek permission for using all the necessary apps.
Your script can then be triggered on a form submit without needing someone to have your spreadsheet open.

```
function initialisePermissions() {
  // MailApp
  MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  // Docs
  var throwawayDoc = DocumentApp.create('Initialising Doc').getId();
  DriveApp.getFileById(throwawayDoc).setTrashed(true);
  // Sheets
  var throwawaySs = SpreadsheetApp.create('throwawaySs').getId();
  DriveApp.getFileById(throwawaySs).setTrashed(true);
  // Forms
  var throwawayForm = FormApp.create('throwawayForm').getId();
  DriveApp.getFileById(throwawayForm).setTrashed(true);
  // Drive
  DriveApp.getStorageLimit();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit").forSpreadsheet(sheet).onFormSubmit().create();

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Thank you, this script can now run when a client submits their booking form."); 

  return;
};
```